# Converting C# Regex into C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, regex, c++-cli

I'm having trouble getting my C# Regex working for C++. In C# I have:

```
 //using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 Regex YourName = new Regex("?<name>\w{3,16}");
```

but in C++ this does not correctly match:

```
 //using namespace System::Text::RegularExpressions;
 Regex^ rx = gcnew Regex("?<name>\w{3,16}", static_cast<RegexOptions>(RegexOptions::Compiled));
```

followed by:

```
 MatchCollection^ matches = rx->Matches( input ); //input=String^
```

Matches always return 0 count. Am I doing something really silly? Is there something special you need to do to convert C# regex into C++ regex? Many thanks for any light you can shed on this.

Comment: That's C#, not C. C has no regexes of any type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` from the compiler, like this:

```
Regex^ rx = gcnew Regex("?<name>\\w{3,16}", static_cast<RegexOptions>(RegexOptions::Compiled));
```

Comment: Wouldn't he need to escape it in the C# one too? OP, are you sure your C# version doesn;'t have a literal string (starts with @"...")?

Comment: hah, yes you're right. Completely missed that. That does fix it though, thanks to both of you.